# How can I prevent maximizing a JavaFX window to fullscreen?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have done this...

```
myStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

which works fine for removing the maximize button but someone can still double click on the window title bar (in Windows) to maximize the window.

I tried this but it does not fire.

```
myStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> prop, Boolean wasIconified, Boolean isIconified) {
                System.out.println("ignore fullscreen");
            }
        });
```

Is there some other way to consume that event so it has no effect?

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish your question, but the event doesn't fire because maximizing is not fullscreen in JavaFX. That would be a window without a window title filling the entire screen. (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#fullScreenProperty())

Answer (score 6):

Actually you are listening to the wrong property the one that you are looking for is `maximizedProperty`

Here is the code to disable window maximize :

```
primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue)
                primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
        });
```

it listens for maximize events then checks whether it's actually maximizing through `if (newVale)` then forces the stage disable maximization.

**hope it helps**

Comment: Thanks, man, this helped a LOT! Should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to your stage

```
myStage.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the user to resize the window at all, you can set the stage's [resizable property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#resizableProperty) to false.

Comment: I'm actually ok with them dragging the corner of the window to make it larger or smaller.  I'm trying to avoid the window jumping to full screen if someone accidentally double-clicks on the title bar.  Unsophisticated users don't know what they did, why it happened or how to undo it.  And this is a small window.  It never needs to occupy the whole screen.

Comment: @Andrew as a general rule: don't gag your users :-) They'll learn platform standards quickly and be annoyed if some app doesn't follow them.

Comment: Yes! @kleopatra, I was just thinking about that, and came back to reply in much the same way. It would be more confusing to me if a window didn't conform to standard conventions. I totally agree.

Comment: I know I could be passing up a valuable teaching moment with the users but I'm ok with that.  If you look at the MS Windows 7 or Windows 8 calculator (calc.exe) double clicking on the title does nothing.  If it jumped to full screen it would probably look silly.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint the stage size ranges

```
myStage.setMaxHeight(500);
myStage.setMaxWidth(600);
```

and probably

```
myStage.setMinHeight(50);
myStage.setMinWidth(60);
```

**EDIT:**
Well, I agree with @kleopatra, window maximizing on double-click is a common behavior on most OS GUIs, sooner or later OS users will be familiar with this. Still restricting stage size will be helpful if your layout gets worse on larger/smaller sizes. And also still want to disable double click behavior, build your own window manager with JavaFX (like an Ensemble app) without depending to one that OS provides.

Comment: restricting the size but still jumping to the upper leading corner of the screen - not much gained by absolute sizing (which is a no-no-never anyway ;-)